# Locale environment variable settings do not take effect

Tags: debian, environment-variables, locale

I have a Debian 6 (64-bit) VPS where I cannot seem to get the locale environment variables LANG and LC_* set. (Everything below as root).

```
vps:~# locale -a
C
POSIX
en_US.utf8
nl_NL.utf8

vps:~# locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=

vps:~# cat /etc/default/locale
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=POSIX
```

This should override the locale settings provided via my SSH client, but the default locale settings take no effect.

.profile, .bashrc, /etc/environment and /etc/profile do not contain any locale settings. I also haven't found any other locations from where these environment variables are sourced.

```
me:~# grep "LANG" ~/.profile ~/.bashrc /etc/environment /etc/profile
me:~# grep "LC_" ~/.profile ~/.bashrc /etc/environment /etc/profile
me:~#
```

My SSH client settings are not taking effect either, while they do on other VPSes. Locally, I have in my /etc/ssh/ssh_config:

```
SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

And on the VPS, /etc/ssh/sshd_config contains:

```
# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

I'm not sure if it's required for the variables to take effect, but my VPS's /etc/pam.d/login contains:

```
# locale variables are also kept into /etc/default/locale in etch
# reading this file *in addition to /etc/environment* does not hurt
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
```

And /etc/pam.d/sshd contains:

```
# Read environment variables from /etc/environment and
# /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
auth       required     pam_env.so # [1]
# In Debian 4.0 (etch), locale-related environment variables were moved to
# /etc/default/locale, so read that as well.
auth       required     pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale
```

(my `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` contains only commented options)

So, it seems something is not allowing either my  /etc/default/locale or my SSH client's locale settings to take effect, so it defaults to POSIX (or something is forcing POSIX explicitly). Any clues what could be interfering? Or ideas how to find out what it is?

I can do `export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` etc. in my .bashrc, and that does work. However I'm trying to understand this behavior, which is different from that on other Debian (6 or 7) installations I'm working with.

Edit: some more details:

- I have rebooted the system, no effect;
- /etc/ssh/sshd_config has `UsePAM yes`;
- I've also tried using `en_US.utf8` as alternative name in `/etc/default/locale`.

Comment: Pointing out the obvious, but the relevant locales *have* been generated, right? You say this does not happen with other VPS's? So probably not the issue. Incidentally, if other VPS's work correctly, why not compare files with them? I've found that a workable debugging strategy in the past.

Comment: Yes, the locales have been generated, see the output of `locale -a` at the top. Comparing the entire system seems like a lot of work, I was hoping for a more targeted approach.

Comment: Not the entire system, just selected files. Anything that involves locales, basically.

Comment: I note that you've checked `/etc/pam.d/login` but that file is only consulted for local logins (e.g. logging in on the console or other serial ports managed by `getty`). For SSH login, you'll want to look at `/etc/pam.d/sshd` instead. Mine does contain the requisite `pam_env.so` line. Does yours? Finally, you could check the output of `env` after logging in by SSH just to make sure the environment variable settings for `LANG` and `LC_CTYPE` are indeed present.

Comment: Ah good call. /etc/pam.d/sshd does contain that line. I've added this to the question.

Comment: Is there a `.bash_profile` in your home on the server? Can you `cd ~ && grep "LANG" *` just to be sure?

Comment: @Jan: just checked my home dir again, there's nothing defining `LANG` or `LC_`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks to me like at no point are those variables exported. What happens if you put `EXPORT` in front of each variable? EG: `EXPORT LC_CTYPE="POSIX"`

Comment: As noted, exporting the variables works. But it should not be necessary: 1) without setting a default locale, the SSH client's locale should take effect, but it doesn't; and 2) when defining a default using e.g. `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, the contents of /etc/default/locale will contain only a variable assignment, so this must be the correct way to configure it. The question is where these POSIX settings come from and why they can't be overridden in the usual manner.

Comment: Let's understand if this is related to ssh: if you connect via ssh with a different user, then export locale variables, then `su -` to root, does it keep the locale settings?

Comment: What exactly is the output of `locale` on the ssh client?

Comment: I don't have the VPS with this problem anymore, so it'll be hard or impossible to verify what the problem was. Locally I would've had `LC_ALL` not set, and all the other variables set with a combination of `en_US.UTF-8` and `nl_NL.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

You should verify that [PermitUserEnvironment] in your sshd config file is set to yes as well. I don't know what the default is.